# version error : what's the version com.datastax.oss that's compatible with java 8 and spark 3.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, cassandra, version, pom.xml

what's the version com.datastax.oss that's compatible with java 8 and spark 3.2.0 .
I can't figure out which version of spark and springboot are compatible.
Is the following code considered correct? if so are the dependencies present valid?
I want to select query in cassandra using spark .
This is the code im working with currently:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/oss/driver/internal/core/util/collection/SimpleQueryPlan
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.newQueryPlan(LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala:122) ~[spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.12-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.newQueryPlan(LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.java:155) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.onThrottleReady(CqlRequestHandler.java:211) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.throttling.PassThroughRequestThrottler.register(PassThroughRequestThrottler.java:52) ~[java-driver-core-4.9.0.jar:na]
```

this code  show an error :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.valoores.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-spark</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cassandra-spark</name>
    <description>datacrowd-cassandra</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-driver-core-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-driver-shaded-guava</artifactId>
    <version>25.1-jre</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: did you build a jar with all dependencies included into your app?

Comment: Yes, under my classpath maven dependencies, I have a jar for each of my dependencies listed in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The compatibility matrix can be found here:

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility

I think you have a dependency problem with java driver 4.9.0. It looks like the minimum driver version should be 4.13.0.

Comment: i have try to add this version 4.13.0 and same error persist